# Función footnote del paquete kableExtra en R devuelve un error de LateX: multicol en ficheros Rmd mientras se hace el knitting a PDF

Tags: r, pdf, markdown

Estaba usando la función footnote del paquete kableExtra para escribir un footnote en una tabla, pero me devuelve el siguiente error de LaTeX:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mulicol.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.126 

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Ejecución interrumpida
```

El código que ejecuto es el siguiente:

````
---
output:
pdf_document:
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: 5
  keep_tex: yes
html_document:
  theme: united
  toc: yes
classoption: table
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{mulicol}
 ---

  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
  ```

  ```{r results='asis'}
  options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE) 
  require(kableExtra)
  cat(kable(head(cars),"latex",digits=c(1,1), longtable 
  =TRUE,row.names=FALSE, 
  caption = "Descriptive analysis for the")%>%footnote(general= 
  "Repeatability 
  (%CV) = ")
  )
  ```
````

Puede ayudarme alguien con este problema?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola user109009, bienvenido/a. El error que estás recibiendo no es de R, sino de Latex (a través de pandoc). Para ayudarte sería necesario que indiques que plataforma (por lo de pandoc.exe debe ser Windows) estás usando y qué distribución de Latex estás usando(MikTex seguramente). El error que te sale es que te falta la librería `multicol` en tu instalación de Latex, que con MikTex se debería instalar automáticamente, pero parece que algo ha fallado.

Comment: La respuesta de @mpaladino indica que hace falta la librería "multicol". El código intenta cargar "mulicol". Probablemente  es un simple error de digitación.

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido/a.
El error que estás recibiendo no es de R, sino de Latex (a través de pandoc), indica que a tu instalación de Latex le falta el paquete `multicol`, requerido por la plantilla que usa `knitr`.

Si estás usando Windows seguramente usas la distribución MiKTeX de Latex. Es un poco raro porque se supone que Miktex instala automáticamente las dependencias (paquetes necesarios, algo similar a como funciona CRAN en R), pero evidentemente eso ha fallado. Te sugiero:

- Asegurarte de que aceptaste la instalación de paquetes adicionales en Miktex.

  - Alternativamente: que tu usuario en la compu tiene privilegios para instalar programas/paquetes. Si estás en una compu administrada (en una oficina) quizás por eso no se te instale el programa.
- Si cuando tratas de hacer el render de Rmarkdown **no** te sale un cuadro de diálogo diciendo que va a instalarse un paquete entonces algo está andando mal. Puedes:

  - Reinstalar MiKTeX con una instalación full, que ya incluirá el paquete necesario (que bien!), pero que ocupa varios gigas con cosas que dificilmente uses (que mal!).
  - Desinstalar MiKTeX del sistema (desde Windows) y reemplazarlo por `tinytex`. Puedes instalar `tinytex` directamente desde R con `install.packages("tinytex"). Ese paquete de R se encarga de instalar en tu sistema una minidistribución de Latex especialmente diseñada para trabajar con` Rmarkdown`y`knitr`. De hecho la hizo la misma persona que hizo` knitr`. [Aquí](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) encuentras bastante información, lamentablemente solo está en inglés.

Creo que esta segunda opción sería la mejor, ya que `tinytex` tiene muy buen manejo de las dependencias de Latex.

Suerte!